When dealing with time, do I add an "and" between the hours and minutes, and minutes themselves?
Por ejemplo, por 22:43 hrs (ie. 10:43 PM), ¿Es esto correcto?:
Son las diez y cuarenta y tres de la noche.

...por
It is ten forty three of the (at) night.


You can also say "son las diez con cuarenta y tres", but for minutes above 30 it is very common and natural to round the time and say "son las once menos cuarto", or even without rounding: "son las once menos diecisiete".

Ambas opciones son correctas, con "y" y sin "y":

Son las diez y cuarenta y tres de la noche.


Son las diez, cuarenta y tres de la noche.

Aunque lo más habitual en español es:

Son las once menos veinte de la noche.

Si se quiere ser más preciso respecto a los minutos de más:

Pasadas las once menos veinte de la noche.


Sí, ¡gracias! Soy pero un estudiante nuevo. Thank you for your explanation here. Although I need to use my dictionary to translate a few words, I do believe I grasp everything you've expressed. Cheers! "Son las diez, cuarenta y tres de la noche.". Entiendo.

"If you want to be more precise". Again, thank you. I haven't worked much with 'menos' yet, but I'm trying ;) Espero ayudar aquí.

Tener en cuenta que algunos países que hablan español usan las horas en formato de 24 horas y otros como Colombia usan las horas en formato de 12 horas agregando el AM o el PM según sea el caso.
